# Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndriodTestBuild'

Tags: java, android

My question is about an error in Android Studio.
Every time when i try to run a java project in Android Studio i get the below error and my program doesn't not work :

[image]

This is my gradle configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.christianmastracco.jsondemo"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

How i can solve it? Thanks

Comment: Please add full build log and your gradle configuration.

Comment: okay thanks now i add

Comment: Your gradle configuration is the contents of your build.gradle file inside app module. And add full build log.

Comment: This is my gradle configuration. And this is the full build log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 27 and this:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

to this

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`, both, into version `27` and implementation version `27.1.1` as shown in error message.

I can't comment at Ernest Zamelczyk answer (reputation 50) but I think the correct answer is `27.1.1`, not `27.1.0` as he told.